# When i enter the position of the array , then its value should become 1

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Initially the whole array will be filled with 0's
when someone enter the position of the soldier then  it's value should be 1.
And finally it should print the final array .

I 've tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int rows,columns,i,n,j,srow,scolumn;
printf("Enter size of the board : \t");
scanf("%d%d",&rows,&columns);
int board[rows][columns]  ;
board[rows][columns] = 0;

for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<columns;j++)
    {

        printf("%d \t",board[rows][columns]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("How many soldiers do you want to place ? : \t");
scanf("%d" , &n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        printf("\n Enter position of the soldier  :\t" );
        scanf("%d%d",&srow,&scolumn);
        board[srow][scolumn] = 1;
    }
}
for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<columns;j++)
    {

        printf("%d \t",board[rows][columns]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: and what is your question? what happens when you run this code?

Comment: when i print the matrix initially are are 0's 
but after assigning the value of 1 to the positon of the soldier the whole matrix is filled with 1's

Comment: ... yes...? what happens after assigning on the second output?

Comment: So you program should generate a board a x b and the user can input x soldier and there position and at each position should appear a 1?

Comment: the complete matrix is filled with 1's ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(If you see code that you can write 'better', then let the code back better than you found it!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    //Variables
    int rows = 0, columns = 0, soldiers = 0, soldierRow = 0, soldierColumn = 0;
    int rowCount = 0, columnCount = 0, soldierCount = 0;


    //Get Board size rows * columns
    printf("Enter size of the board(rows and column):\n>");
    scanf("%d %d", &rows, &columns);

    int board[rows][columns];

    //Initialize board
    for(rowCount = 0; rowCount < rows; rowCount++) {
        for(columnCount = 0; columnCount < columns; columnCount++)
            board[rowCount][columnCount] = 0;
    }

    //Show the board
    for(rowCount = 0; rowCount < rows; rowCount++) {
        for(columnCount = 0; columnCount < columns; columnCount++)
            printf("%2d\t", board[rowCount][columnCount]);
        printf("\n");
    }


    //Check that no more soldiers is entered that there is space
    do {

        //Error Message
        if(soldiers > (rows*columns))
            printf("\nThere isn't enough space for so many soliders!\n");

        //Read in Soldier
        printf("How many soldiers do you want to place?\n>");
        scanf("%d" , &soldiers);

    } while(soldiers > (rows*columns));

    //Check that it's a valid position on the board
    for(soldierCount = 0; soldierCount < soldiers; soldierCount++) {

        do {

            //Read in the position
            printf("\nEnter position of the soldier(row and column):\n>" );
            scanf("%d %d" ,&soldierRow, &soldierColumn);

            //Error Message
            if((soldierRow < 1 ||  soldierRow > rows || soldierColumn < 1 || soldierColumn > columns))
                printf("\nThe soldier position is out of the board size!");

        } while(soldierRow < 1 ||  soldierRow > rows || soldierColumn < 1 || soldierColumn > columns);

        board[soldierRow-1][soldierColumn-1] = 1;

    }

    //Print the board again
    for(rowCount = 0; rowCount < rows; rowCount++) {
        for(columnCount = 0; columnCount < columns; columnCount++)
            printf("%d \t",board[rowCount][columnCount]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Possible input/output:

```
Enter size of the board(rows and column):
>4 4
 0       0       0       0
 0       0       0       0
 0       0       0       0
 0       0       0       0
How many soldiers do you want to place?
>17

There isn't enough space for so many soliders!
How many soldiers do you want to place?
>2

Enter position of the soldier(row and column):
>23 23

The soldier position is out of the board size!
Enter position of the soldier(row and column):
>2 2

Enter position of the soldier(row and column):
>3 3
0       0       0       0
0       1       0       0
0       0       1       0
0       0       0       0
```

Comment: @user3699528 Your welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: Now i updated my answer again and it has a little bit error checking in it, so you can't have more soldier then the size of the board and you can't put the soldier out of range.)

Comment: ya , even the  soldiers should'nt be placed in same positions .

Comment: not <= and >= , just < and > in the do while loop. give the position of the soldier as 4 4 in the above example it tells "There isn't enough space for so many soliders!" @Rizier123

Comment: @user3699528 updated it thanks for the note! (BTW you also can upvote now)

Comment: (done ;)) now working on soldier positions, if 2 soldiers enter the same position another error line should show op ! @Rizier123

Comment: @user3699528 should that be a question or are you doing that?

Answer (score 3):

You have a bug in both your loops:

```
for(i=0;i<rows;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<columns;j++) {
        printf("%d \t",board[rows][columns]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Should be:

```
for(i=0;i<rows;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<columns;j++) {
        printf("%d \t",board[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

After fixing this you will also notice you are not initializing the array correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print uninitalized values, here

```
board[rows][columns] = 0;
```

you to access an element beyond the array, since the last element of the array is

```
board[rows - 1][columns - 1] = 0;
```

and the previous line will only initialize to `0` the last element, it surely didn't print `0`s, did it?, to initialize all the elements to `0` do it this way

```
memset(board, 0, columns * rows * sizeof(int));
```

The previous line, can also be

```
memset(board, 0, sizeof(board));
```

And please check that `srow < rows` and `scolumn < columns` before this line

```
board[srow][scolumn] = 1;
```

there is another problem, here

```
for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<columns;j++)
    {
        printf("%d \t",board[i /*i <-- rows */][j /*j <-- columns */]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `sizeof board` is less error-prone than `columns * rows * sizeof(int)`

Comment: @MattMcNabb you had told me that in other posts. But I keep forgettig it.